# How to use reverse() in django on included URLs?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

My urls.py looks roughly like this:

```
...
url(r'^advance-day/$', 'mafia.views.advance_day', name='advance_day'),
url(r'^form/', include(form_urls)),
...
```

I recently moved things to a separate `form_urls.py` for form URLs because there are a lot of forms, and I want to not have them in the way. However, I then can't figure out how to use `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()` on them without using the whole name of the view. I can do `reverse(mafia.views.investigation_form)` for example, but I'd prefer to be able to do `reverse(form_urls:investigation)` or something.

I also have the same problem in templates. Before I convert every instance of `{% url sign_up %}` into `{% url mafia.views.sign_up %}`, etc. I'd like to try doing this with names still. Is there  way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is solved by [namespacing of url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces):

To start with, add add a `namespace` argument to your master `urls.py` for your included urls:

```
url(r'form/', include(form_urls, namespace='forms')),
```

Assuming you have the following in `form_urls`:

```
url(r'my-form/$', 'mafia.views.my_form', name='my_form'),
```

You can then reverse it with `{% urls forms:my_form %}`.